# derivative of flow

Tags: differential-geometry

If I have a vector field $V$ on a manifold $M$ with flow $V_t$, and a curve $\gamma(s):\mathbb{R}\to M$, how do I compute
$$\frac{d}{ds}\Bigg\vert_{s=0} V_t \gamma(s)?$$

I expect it to be a tangent vector at $V_t\gamma(0)$ and to involve the connection on $M$ somehow, but I'm at a loss for how to derive the correct expression. Similarly, if $W$ is a second vector field, how do I compute
$$\frac{d}{ds}\Bigg\vert_{s=0} (V+sW)_t p$$
for some $p\in M$? This is again a tangent vector at $V_tp$, and I expect the Lie bracket to appear, since when $[V,W]=0$ the answer is clearly just $W(V_tp)$.

Comment: Please, tell me, what you mean by $V_t\gamma(s)$?

Comment: Is this the flow at $t$ and the point $\gamma(s)$?

Comment: @LeonardoFranciscoCavenaghi The flow of the point $\gamma(s)$ along $V$ for time $t$

Comment: Sorry, let me try again:
$$\frac{d}{ds}V_t(\gamma(s)) = \nabla_{\gamma'(s)}V_t(\gamma(s)).$$

Comment: @LeonardoFranciscoCavenaghi What do you mean by $\gamma^t(s)$?

Comment: Is $\gamma'(s) = \frac{d}{ds}\gamma(s)$

Comment: @LeonardoFranciscoCavenaghi So if I understand, you are saying that it is $\left[\nabla_{\gamma'(0)} f\right](\gamma(0))$ for $f:M\to M, p \mapsto V_tp$. I suppose that is true, but is there no way to simplify this derivative?

Comment: Is exactly what you said. In fact there is no how to simplify this. If you know something about bundles you can note that the connection $\nabla = d + A$ where $A$ will mean the matrix os Christoffel symbols. The question is that if you write $\gamma$ in coordinates then you can clarify what I said, you will get the equation in terms of the Christoffel symbols, that determines the connection unically.

Comment: No connection is involved - you're only differentiating maps between manifolds, not vector fields etc. Your first derivative is simply $DV_t (\gamma'(0)) = \gamma'(0)V_t$ - this is as simple as derivatives come, I'm not sure what kind of simplification you're hoping for. The only way to reduce the flow of $V$ back to $V$ itself is by differentiating in $t$.  $V_t$ is pretty much an arbitrary map in this situation.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can expand your second expression in the general case without using some ugly series like the Zassenhaus formula - I doubt you can get a closed-form expression unless you also differentiate in the $t$ direction.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Thanks. I suppose I was hoping for something of the form $$\int \left(\textrm{something involving the parallel transport of }\gamma'(0)\textrm{ along } V\right)dt$$ but I have no grounds for this.

Comment: That might be possible - try treating $DV_t (\gamma'(0))$ as a vector field along $V_t (\gamma(0))$ and taking the covariant derivative along the curve. You should be able to integrate this in some fashion to get your expression in terms of $\gamma'(0)$ and some integral.